# AWS API Gateway caching SSL & DNS lookup to improve response times

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, tcp, aws-api-gateway

I've been working on improving performance of my APIs hosted on various AWS services this week, and I've found that a significant portion of the time on some of the non-Lambda calls (namely ECS) is taken by DNS Lookup, TCP Handshake, and SSL Handshake. Below are the response times broken down by Postman.

[The endpoint pointing to an ECS service does not cache the handshakes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWlES.png)

[Headers returned by ECS endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxFEZ.png)

[The endpoint pointing to a Lambda does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGqN3.png)

[Headers returned by Lambda endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SLcS.png)

**More details:**

Both services are hosted in the same zone, the API Gateway for both is also hosted in the same zone, the only difference is that for the Lambda, the route goes from Route53 -> API Gateway -> Lambda integration, where the ECS goes Route53 -> API Gateway -> Application load balancer (private VPC link, HTTP) -> ECS service, the service being an NGINX reverse proxy listening for HTTP and routing those requests to a Django container hosted in the same service.

**Question:**

I'm looking to enable or set up caching for the ECS service in order to cut down response times to below or close to 100ms. I haven't found any details on this caching behavior or by extension how to set it up. How can I go about setting it up, and perhaps read more about this behavior? Thanks

Comment: What is the endpoint or can you put all the headers + values returned into your question please.

Comment: @Tobin added the response headers

Answer (score 1):

Does the Lambda request come second? The cache will reuse the same handshake for each sub/domain within the session, so the first should always have a penalty. Caching the DNS is generally at machine level, but TLS/SSL has to be handshook on every new session.

In both situations, it is API Gateway which terminates your public SSL. API Gateway makes a separate internal request to Lambda or ECS. Depending how you have setup your routing, you could also remove the API Gateway from the ECS route and have the NGINX terminate SSL and serve the certificate and remove one of the (slower) hops?

Comment: What do you mean by come second? I should have clarified, they aren't sequential, they are separate calls with separate functions. You're right, the first call to Lambda does the full handshake and lookup, but every subsequent call for a few hours seems to cache all 3 of those elements.

I'm using API Gateway on the cluster primarily as a security measure, as it handles auth for me. I found that handling auth in Django was actually quite slow, and I figured the engineers at Amazon probably had a better solution for it ready to go than I could develop, so I opted to move auth to the gateway.